# Unable to access new OFBiz 16.11 plugin

Tags: java, apache, ofbiz

I am trying to learn OFBiz 16.11, but I am facing an error when adding a new plugin and tying to access it using its url.

```
:ERROR MESSAGE:
org.apache.ofbiz.widget.renderer.ScreenRenderException: Error rendering screen [component://common/widget/CommonScreens.xml#login]: org.apache.ofbiz.widget.renderer.ScreenRenderException: Error rendering screen [component://ofbizDemo/widget/CommonScreens.xml#main-decorator]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find resource bundle [OfbizDemoUiLabels] in the locale [en_US] (Could not find resource bundle [OfbizDemoUiLabels] in the locale [en_US]) (Error rendering screen [component://ofbizDemo/widget/CommonScreens.xml#main-decorator]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find resource bundle [OfbizDemoUiLabels] in the locale [en_US] (Could not find resource bundle [OfbizDemoUiLabels] in the locale [en_US]))
```

I ran the following commands to create a new plugin:

```
--Initialize OFBiz and load demo data
gradlew cleanAll loadDefault ofbiz

--Add new plugin
gradlew createPlugin -PpluginId=ofbizDemo 

--Apply changes and run OFBiz
gradlew loadDefault ofbiz
```

I am currently testing OFBiz using Windows 10.
New plugin URL: https://localhost:8443/ofbizDemo

Is there any missing step during the creation of the new plugin which is causing this error message?

Note that the above commands can be found in OFBiz tutorial document:
[Tutorial Document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/%5BWIP%5D+OFBiz+Tutorial+-+A+Beginners+Development+Guide+for+16.11)

I checked the OfbizDemoUiLabels.xml file and it exists in its correct location.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution. Simply removed all non-English entries in the `OfbizDemoUiLabels.xml` file. It is now working as expected!

Comment: Yes it works for me too. seems like issue in internationalization.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because the current language has been set to English (United States) [en-US]. Just change the language to "English- [en]" from the top right "language" menu, at left of "logout" and "visual themes".

[image: language settings]

Alternatively, edit the config file:
apache-ofbiz-16.11.xx\specialpurpose\ofbizDemo\config\OfbizDemoUiLabels.xml

Replace all-

```
<value xml:lang="en">OfbizDemo Application</value>
```

With

```
<value xml:lang="en-US">OfbizDemo Application</value>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem. I solved it by adding entries for my system's default language (which is german) to the OfbizDemoUiLabels.xml,
e.g. `<value xml:lang="de">OfbizDemo Applikation</value>`